# Desktop Switching Shortcuts not working at all!

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspace-switcher

Some time ago I was tampering with Settings and installing new applications and I somehow disabled desktop switching by shortcut (I think It was CairoDock that did it). Now I always have to click on the Workspace switcher icon and go to other desktop.

However the strange part is that the shortcuts are there in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

I changed them for other random shortcuts, but nothing worked.

And even in `ccsm`, I enabled `Put` or `Desktop Wall` and configured the shortcuts, but they didn't work either.

Can someone help me now, how to enable desktop switching by the usual shortcuts like Ctrl+alt+Left? Thanks in advance.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, if it helps.